# Attaching crypto to a message stored on IPFS

Tags: go-ethereum, ipfs

I want to send a message to another user and attach some eth with this message with the condition that the receiver should only be the person who can claim that crypto.

Step1:Write a message, store it on IPFS and get the content hash.
Step2: Store this hash against the recipient address in the smart contract.
Step3: Send the desired crypto to a smart contract function REDEEM which will only give away the crypto if the signed hash of the content will be made available.

Step4: Recipient checks the smart contract and sees all the messages that have been shared with him and fetches their content hashes.
Step5: If he wants to redeem the crypto attached to a particular message, He will sign the message and send it to the REDEEM function of the smart contract.
Step6: REDEEM function checks two things, if the content hash does belong to the recipient and if yes, If the message signature is valid or not. If yes, Transfer the crypto to the recipient.

My question is: Does the signature even required to check if the content hash belongs to the recipient or not?

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt seem like a signature would be required if you use msg.sender to check that the recipient is using the wallet address of the intended recipient to claim the crypto.

Can you clarify a few details so that I can better understand the context of the question?

Does the recipient already have a wallet address that is known?

When you say "crypto attached to the message" do you really mean that the crypto is stored in the smart contract with the REDEEM function? If this is the case then the messages stored on ipfs probably are not needed in any way to verify the recipient, unless the recipient does not already have a known wallet address.

Is the recipient signing the ipfs content with a wallet adresses signature? Or are they signing it with their actual name and then sending  a hash of ipfs message contents + recipients name

For example: ipfs message reads "the message is the address" and the recipiebts name is "dr. Private key"

Would the recipient send a hash of ("the message is the address"+"dr. Private key") from any wallet address to the contract and out pops the crypto or would the recipient need to use a specific wallet address to send a signed message with the content hash of the ipfs "message" to the redeem contract in order to claim the crypto